# Windows 8.1 Sideloaded app for Assigned Access

Tags: windows-8.1, kiosk

I have a windows 8 application that will be used for an event in a kiosk. Since this is a limited time event, and this application is not meant for broad distribution, this app has no reason to be listed in the app store. But, because this app needs to be the only app the user should be able to interact with, it needs to be assignable as the app for assigned access mode.

It seem the only apps available for assigned access are apps that were pre-installed with the OS such as calculator and maps. Apps downloaded from the store, such as Amazon, or our sideloaded application (installed via power shell) do not appear as options.

Microsoft documentation says that the restriction is that the application assigned must be a modern app, but it appears we have meat this requirement? Is there something more that should be done to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out.

Once you create your user that you intend on being your kiosk mode user, you must sign in at least once without the account being in assigned access mode, so all the windows account stuff can get created, and then, importantly install the application that you want to use, under that user accounts credentials. Then log out, and sign in as the administrator. You will see the appropriate apps show on this list now.